# Sequnce of tenses in the sentence

Tags: tenses, sentence, passive-voice, sequence-of-tenses

Is it okay to use different tenses in this way?

> Try to  find an area where science **isn't** needed, where experiments **weren't**
>   perfomed.

Comment: Okay? Yes, although many may prefer to use *have not been*. But the question is whether it says what you want it to? To me it sounds like present tense would be best throughout.

Comment: Yes, and all past tense would be fine, too.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602378/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly two different tenses is perfectly fine, and in fact, changing the second to present tense, as was suggested, would completely change it's meaning.
As written, the implication is there are areas where experiments were simply not performed.  If you change this to *aren't* performed, it implies that as a rule, experiments are not performed in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say the whole sentence in present tense: "Try to find an area where science isn't needed, where experiments aren't perfomed." to keep the consistency. Although your version is just fine too.